# select from oracle table where column in sqlserver table

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

I have a table in oracle that contains records of customers and another table in Microsoft SQL server that contains over 30,000 records of certain flagged customers . Now, I want to select from the oracle where a column has values in Microsoft SQL server. Like this:

```
SELECT oracleTable.custname 
FROM oracleTable 
WHERE oracleTable.idcol IN (/*LIST OF VALUES FROM SQL SERVER TABLE*/)
```

And i dont have priviledge to create tables on the oracle database.

I have to create a function in C# that returns the list values in this format `'1','2','3','4'` and concatenate it with to my command text but with the Microsoft SQL server table containing records more than 30,000, oracle complains that it only allows 1,000 in a list.

Does anybody know a workaround (C# or TSQL)?

Comment: Did you search for answer in Google

Comment: Let me do that for you.. https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=access+sql+server+from+oracle+database

Comment: yes and i didn't find any helpful answer.

Comment: I thought of using linked servers but i am not even allowed to install anything on the server. I have to send a request through some chain of commands before they decide whether or not to install for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle create a temporary table, insert the values, and then join.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the limitations that you have mentioned i think you should consider to code it using C# ... you will have the flexibility of DataTables. Fill one DataTable with SQL Server data and another with Oracle. Now you can get the required data using Linq.

Hope this helps.